# Does Github pages support webpack proxy?

Tags: webpack, github-pages, webpack-dev-server

I have a small app built with React + Webpack, and i have config the proxy for webpack to handle the request. Does Github pages support it?

It seems not working as far as i have tried.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, github pages is a static site, so for http request you should use a server environment.

For example, you can deploy your app to heroku.